# Concatenating strings doesn't work as expected

Tags: c++, operator-keyword, string-concatenation, stdstring, standard-library

I know it is a common issue, but looking for references and other material I don't find a clear answer to this question.

Consider the following code:

```
#include <string>

// ...
// in a method
std::string a = "Hello ";
std::string b = "World";
std::string c = a + b;
```

The compiler tells me it cannot find an overloaded operator for `char[dim]`.

Does it mean that in the string there is not a + operator?

But in several examples there is a situation like this one. If this is not the correct way to concat more strings, what is the best way?

Comment: Your code should compile just fine, which means you're not showing the exact code that causes the error (on top of not posting the exact error message).

Comment: Well it does not work... Probably my fault is that I didn't provide compiler... it's g++ not vc... :)

Answer (score 155, accepted):

Your code, as written, works. You’re probably trying to achieve something unrelated, but similar:

```
std::string c = "hello" + "world";
```

This doesn’t work because for C++ this seems like you’re trying to add two `char` pointers. Instead, you *need* to convert at least one of the `char*` literals to a `std::string`. Either you can do what you’ve already posted in the question (as I said, this code *will* work) or you do the following:

```
std::string c = std::string("hello") + "world";
```

Comment: Thank you very much... ok it works... I expected this was the problem... but really.... There is not a well provided operator to concat two strings (I mean two char*)????? this is really strange... Is there a reason why standard libraries do not support such a simple thing (I guess there must be one).

Comment: char* is a pointer, and cannot be added simply because it requires an allocation of memory. std::strings hide allocation, this is why it is possible to provide an operator+ for them.

Comment: @Andry: The reason this doesn't work is that C++ inherits its string literals from C, which is why they are of the type `const char[]`, rather than `std::string`. In C (and therefore also in C++) arrays decay to pointers very easily, which is why "a"+"b" will invoke the built-in operator that adds two pointers. The result of that (a pointer pointing somewhere into memory) is of course quite useless, but nevertheless this is what we're stuck with.

Comment: @Vincent Thank you. Well it's a reasonable explaination...

Comment: @Andry: reasonable but wrong. Allocation has got nothing to do with this. The explanation given by @sbi is the correct one (apart from the fact that the result of a pointer addition isn’t another pointer – it’s simply impossible to add two pointers, since the result would be meaningless).

Comment: @Konrad True, operator+ cannot be overriden for (char*,char*) and the compiler does not let you add pointer. If it would be possible, it would still be a bad idea because adding those 2 pointers would require an allocation for the result string. Or it could return an std::string but that would make STL far more intrusive than it should be.

Comment: Additionally, directly adjacent string literals are automatically concatenated by the compiler.
`std::string c = "Hello" "world";`, for example, will result in `c == "Helloworld"`.

Comment: You can also use string literals: `std;:string c = "hello"s + "world"s;` or just make one of them a `std::string`.

Answer (score 46):

```
std::string a = "Hello ";
a += "World";
```

Comment: Would be +1 if i had upvotes left!

Comment: Sorry its C++ not C# i += doesn't work here, for which it is used

Comment: @Pratik [You sure?](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%2B%3D)

Answer (score 5):

I would do this:

```
std::string a("Hello ");
std::string b("World");
std::string c = a + b;
```

Which compiles in VS2008.

Comment: Should also work in gcc.

Answer (score 5):

```
std::string a = "Hello ";
std::string b = "World ";
std::string c = a;
c.append(b);
```