# suppress NAs in paste()

Tags: r, paste, na

### Regarding the bounty

[Ben Bolker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/190277/ben-bolker)'s `paste2`-solution produces a `""` when the strings that are pasted contains `NA`'s in the same position. Like this,

```
> paste2(c("a","b", "c", NA), c("A","B", NA, NA))
[1] "a, A" "b, B" "c"    ""
```

The fourth element is an `""` instead of an `NA` Like this,

```
[1] "a, A" "b, B" "c"  NA
```

I'm offering up this small bounty for anyone who can fix this.

### Original question

I've read the help page `?paste`, but I don't understand how to have R ignore `NA`s. I do the following,

```
foo <- LETTERS[1:4]
foo[4] <- NA
foo
[1] "A" "B" "C" NA
paste(1:4, foo, sep = ", ")
```

and get

```
[1] "1, A"  "2, B"  "3, C"  "4, NA"
```

What I would like to get,

```
[1] "1, A" "2, B" "3, C" "4"
```

I could do like this,

```
sub(', NA$', '', paste(1:4, foo, sep = ", "))
[1] "1, A" "2, B" "3, C" "4"
```

but that seems like a detour.

Comment: if you have a recurrent need , you can implement your paste2(...,sep,collapse,na.rm=FALE) with na.rm argument for exemple.

Comment: @agstudy, how do I do that?

Comment: `stringr::str_replace_na(c(NA, "abc", "def"), replacement="")` -- 2018 way

Comment: replacing the NA with an empty string won't work with paste. From `paste(1:4, stringr::str_replace_na(foo, replacement=""), sep=", ")` you get `"1, A" "2, B" "3, C" "4, "`

Answer (score 48, accepted):

For the purpose of a "true-NA": Seems the most direct route is just to modify the value returned by `paste2` to be `NA` when the value is `""`

```
 paste3 <- function(...,sep=", ") {
     L <- list(...)
     L <- lapply(L,function(x) {x[is.na(x)] <- ""; x})
     ret <-gsub(paste0("(^",sep,"|",sep,"$)"),"",
                 gsub(paste0(sep,sep),sep,
                      do.call(paste,c(L,list(sep=sep)))))
     is.na(ret) <- ret==""
     ret
     }
 val<- paste3(c("a","b", "c", NA), c("A","B", NA, NA))
 val
#[1] "a, A" "b, B" "c"    NA
```

Comment: Is this intended
`paste3(c("a", "b", "c", NA), c("A", "B", NA, NA), sep = "|")` returns
`[1] "|a|||A|" "|b|||B|" "|c|||"   "|||"  `?
In contrast
`paste(c("a", "b", "c", NA), c("A", "B", NA, NA), sep = "|")` returns
`[1] "a|A"   "b|B"   "c|NA"  "NA|NA"`

Comment: It's not intended. If you need to use "|" as a separator, then realize that it was being used inside the function to act as a logical OR in a regex pattern. So there ought to be a trap to that particular separator and alternate processing.

Answer (score 57):

I know this question is many years old, but it's still the top google result for `r paste na`. I was looking for a quick solution to what I assumed was a simple problem, and was somewhat taken aback by the complexity of the answers. I opted for a different solution, and am posting it here in case anyone else is interested.

```
bar <- apply(cbind(1:4, foo), 1, 
        function(x) paste(x[!is.na(x)], collapse = ", "))
bar
[1] "1, A" "2, B" "3, C" "4"
```

In case it isn't obvious, this will work on any number of vectors with `NA`s in any positions.

IMHO, the advantage of this over the existing answers is legibility. It's a one-liner, which is always nice, and it doesn't rely on a bunch of regexes and if/else statements which may trip up your colleagues or future self. [Erik Shitts' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13673985/3204472) mostly shares these advantages, but assumes there are only two vectors and that only the last of them contains `NA`s.

My solution doesn't satisfy the requirement in your edit, because my project has the opposite requirement. However, you can easily solve this by adding a second line borrowed from [42-'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15673180/3204472):

```
is.na(bar) <- bar == ""
```

Comment: This worked for me. Very simple. I wish this was shipped with paste.

Answer (score 49):

I found a `dplyr`/`tidyverse` solution to that question, which is rather elegant in my opinion.

```
library(tidyr)
foo <- LETTERS[1:4] 
foo[4] <- NA 
df <- data.frame(foo, num = 1:4)
df %>% unite(., col = "New.Col",  num, foo, na.rm=TRUE, sep = ",")
>    New.Col
  1:     1,A
  2:     2,B
  3:     3,C
  4:       4
```

Comment: Why loading `data.table` and all `tidyverse` packages if it is only about `unite`?

Comment: Because I just wanted to make sure it works and I am using both dplyr and data.table. I rather load more than necessary than have non-reproducible code.

Comment: Perfect. This a great one-line solution to replace the previous clunky (but required without dplyr) ones.

Comment: One again `dplyr` provides an elegant solution

Comment: FYI: `unite` is in `tidyr` package, so no need to load `data.table` & the entire `tidyverse` for this if you need to keep your dependencies tidy.

Comment: I've removed the unnecessary dependencies. :-)

Answer (score 16):

A function that follows up on @ErikShilt's answer and @agstudy's comment.  It generalizes the situation slightly by allowing `sep` to be specified and handling cases where *any* element (first, last, or intermediate) is `NA`. (It might break if there are multiple `NA` values in a row, or in other tricky cases ...) By the way, note that this situation is described exactly in the second paragraph of the `Details` section of `?paste`, which indicates that at least the R authors are aware of the situation (although no solution is offered).

```
paste2 <- function(...,sep=", ") {
    L <- list(...)
    L <- lapply(L,function(x) {x[is.na(x)] <- ""; x})
    gsub(paste0("(^",sep,"|",sep,"$)"),"",
                gsub(paste0(sep,sep),sep,
                     do.call(paste,c(L,list(sep=sep)))))
}
foo <- c(LETTERS[1:3],NA)
bar <- c(NA,2:4)
baz <- c("a",NA,"c","d")
paste2(foo,bar,baz)
# [1] "A, a"    "B, 2"    "C, 3, c" "4, d"
```

This doesn't handle @agstudy's suggestions of (1) incorporating the optional `collapse` argument; (2) making `NA`-removal optional by adding an `na.rm` argument (and setting the default to `FALSE` to make `paste2` backward compatible with `paste`).  If one wanted to make this more sophisticated (i.e. remove multiple sequential `NA`s) or faster it might make sense to write it in C++ via Rcpp (I don't know much about C++'s string-handling, but it might not be too hard -- see [convert Rcpp::CharacterVector to std::string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8421250/convert-rcppcharactervector-to-stdstring) and [Concatenating strings doesn't work as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4304662/c-concatenating-strings) for a start ...)

Comment: I think you change your do.call by  do.call(paste,c(L,list(sep=sep,collapse=collapse))))) and you get your collapse argument

Comment: yes, it's not hard -- I just didn't bother (yet). Feel free to edit if you like (oops, you can't -- requires 2000 rep -- sorry.)

Answer (score 13):

As [Ben Bolker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/190277/ben-bolker) mentioned the above approaches may fall over if there are multiple NAs in a row. I tried a different approach that seems to overcome this.

```
paste4 <- function(x, sep = ", ") {
  x <- gsub("^\\s+|\\s+$", "", x) 
  ret <- paste(x[!is.na(x) & !(x %in% "")], collapse = sep)
  is.na(ret) <- ret == ""
  return(ret)
  }
```

The second line strips out extra whitespace introduced when concatenating text and numbers.
The above code can be used to concatenate multiple columns (or rows) of a dataframe using the `apply` command, or repackaged to first coerce the data into a dataframe if needed.

```
EDIT
```

After a few more hours thought I think the following code incorporates the suggestions above to allow specification of the collapse and na.rm options.

```
paste5 <- function(..., sep = " ", collapse = NULL, na.rm = F) {
  if (na.rm == F)
    paste(..., sep = sep, collapse = collapse)
  else
    if (na.rm == T) {
      paste.na <- function(x, sep) {
        x <- gsub("^\\s+|\\s+$", "", x)
        ret <- paste(na.omit(x), collapse = sep)
        is.na(ret) <- ret == ""
        return(ret)
      }
      df <- data.frame(..., stringsAsFactors = F)
      ret <- apply(df, 1, FUN = function(x) paste.na(x, sep))

      if (is.null(collapse))
        ret
      else {
        paste.na(ret, sep = collapse)
      }
    }
}
```

As above, `na.omit(x)` can be replaced with `(x[!is.na(x) & !(x %in% "")` to also drop empty strings if desired. Note, using collapse with na.rm = T returns a string without any "NA", though this could be changed by replacing the last line of code with `paste(ret, collapse = collapse)`.

```
nth <- paste0(1:12, c("st", "nd", "rd", rep("th", 9)))
mnth <- month.abb
nth[4:5] <- NA
mnth[5:6] <- NA

paste5(mnth, nth)
[1] "Jan 1st"  "Feb 2nd"  "Mar 3rd"  "Apr NA"   "NA NA"    "NA 6th"   "Jul 7th"  "Aug 8th"  "Sep 9th"  "Oct 10th" "Nov 11th" "Dec 12th"

paste5(mnth, nth, sep = ": ", collapse = "; ", na.rm = T)
[1] "Jan: 1st; Feb: 2nd; Mar: 3rd; Apr; 6th; Jul: 7th; Aug: 8th; Sep: 9th; Oct: 10th; Nov: 11th; Dec: 12th"

paste3(c("a","b", "c", NA), c("A","B", NA, NA), c(1,2,NA,4), c(5,6,7,8))
[1] "a, A, 1, 5" "b, B, 2, 6" "c, , 7"     "4, 8" 

paste5(c("a","b", "c", NA), c("A","B", NA, NA), c(1,2,NA,4), c(5,6,7,8), sep = ", ", na.rm = T)
[1] "a, A, 1, 5" "b, B, 2, 6" "c, 7"       "4, 8"
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use `ifelse`, a vectorized if-else construct to determine if a value is NA and substitute a blank. You'll then use gsub to strip out the trailing ", " if it isn't followed by any other string.

```
gsub(", $", "", paste(1:4, ifelse(is.na(foo), "", foo), sep = ", "))
```

Your answer is correct. There isn't a better way to do it. This issue is explicitly mentioned in the [paste documentation](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/paste.html) in the Details section.

Comment: Thank you for responding to my question, but your code still leaves me with `"4, "`, what I'm looking for is `"4"`.

Comment: @EricFail, sorry I didn't notice the lack of ", " on the last element. Your answer is the correct one.

Comment: That solves my question as is, thanks. So, there is no way to change the behaviour of `past()`?

Comment: @EricFail `paste` is fine the way it is.  You want to use it to do something non-standard so it makes sense that you should have to do a little more work to specify the behavior that you want.  The way it currently works is fine IMO.

Comment: @Dason, I'm not saying paste is not fine, I am simply trying to solve an issue I thought other people would also have. In my "real" example I have a lot of variables that I am trying to combine into one vector. I guess there is no short cut to solve this problem. regardless, thankful for the responses!

Comment: if the above code would work for `x` as
`x = gsub(",$", "", paste(1:4, ifelse(is.na(foo), "", foo), sep = ","))`
then in order to get rid of the trailing `","`  in it just repeat it once again
`x = gsub(",$", "", x)`
It worked for me to get rid of that annoying `"4,"` last comma

Answer (score 6):

If working with df or tibbles using tidyverse, I use `mutate_all` or `mutate_at` with `str_replace_na` before `paste` or `unite` to avoid pasting NAs.

```
library(tidyverse)
new_df <- df  %>%
mutate_all(~str_replace_na(., "")) %>%
mutate(combo_var = paste0(var1, var2, var3))
```

OR

```
new_df <- df  %>%
mutate_at(c('var1', 'var2'), ~str_replace_na(., "")) %>%
mutate(combo_var = paste0(var1, var2))
```

Comment: `unite` has the option to set `na.rm = TRUE`, so you could skip the `mutate` steps and call something like `df %>% unite('col3', col1:col2, sep = ' ', na.rm = TRUE)`. It's worth noting that the default `sep` argument is an underscore. Also worth noting that `na.rm = TRUE` might not work as expected if one or more of the columns being combined is numeric.

Answer (score 3):

This can be acheived in a single line.
For e.g.,

```
vec<-c("A","B",NA,"D","E")
res<-paste(vec[!is.na(vec)], collapse=',' )
print(res)
[1] "A,B,D,E"
```

Answer (score 2):

Or remove the NAs after paste with str_replace_all

```
data$1 <- str_replace_all(data$1, "NA", "")
```

Comment: There are other answers that provide the OP's question, and they were posted many years ago. When posting an answer, please make sure you add either a new solution, or a substantially better explanation, especially when answering older questions.

Answer (score 1):

A variant of Joe's solution (https://stackoverflow.com/a/49201394/3831096) that respects both `sep` and `collapse` and returns NA when all values are NA is:

```
paste_missing <- function(..., sep=" ", collapse=NULL) {
  ret <-
    apply(
      X=cbind(...),
      MARGIN=1,
      FUN=function(x) {
        if (all(is.na(x))) {
          NA_character_
        } else {
          paste(x[!is.na(x)], collapse = sep)
        }
      }
    )
  if (!is.null(collapse)) {
    paste(ret, collapse=collapse)
  } else {
    ret
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that behaves more like paste and handles more edge cases than current solutions (empty strings, "NA" strings, more than 2 arguments, use of collapse argument...).

```r
paste2 <- function(..., sep = " ", collapse = NULL, na.rm = FALSE){
  # in default case, use paste 
  if(!na.rm) return(paste(..., sep = sep, collapse = collapse))
  # cbind is convenient to recycle, it warns though so use suppressWarnings
  dots <- suppressWarnings(cbind(...))
  res <- apply(dots, 1, function(...) {
    if(all(is.na(c(...)))) return(NA)
    do.call(paste, as.list(c(na.omit(c(...)), sep = sep)))
  })
  if(is.null(collapse)) res else
   paste(na.omit(res), collapse = collapse)
}

# behaves like `paste()` by default
paste2(c("a","b", "c", NA), c("A","B", NA, NA))
#> [1] "a A"   "b B"   "c NA"  "NA NA"

# trigger desired behavior by setting `na.rm = TRUE` and `sep = ", "`
paste2(c("a","b", "c", NA), c("A","B", NA, NA), sep = ",", na.rm = TRUE)
#> [1] "a,A" "b,B" "c"   NA

# handles hedge cases
paste2(c("a","b", "c", NA, "", "",   ""),
       c("a","b", "c", NA, "", "", "NA"),
       c("A","B",  NA, NA, NA, "",   ""), 
       sep = ",", na.rm = TRUE)
#> [1] "a,a,A" "b,b,B" "c,c"   NA      ","     ",,"    ",NA,"
```

<sup>Created on 2019-10-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Small overview of the `tidyverse` solutions:

```
library(tidyverse)
dat <- tibble(x = c("a", "b", NA,  NA),
              y = c("A",  NA, NA, "D"))

### str_c()
### missing values are "infectious"
dat %>% 
  mutate(z = str_c(x, y))

### str_c() and str_replace_na()
### difficult sytax
dat %>% 
  mutate(across(c(x, y), ~ str_replace_na(.x, replacement = ""), .names = "{.col}r"),
         z = str_c(xr, yr))

### unite()
### unintuitive to use something different than mutate()...
dat %>% 
  unite(col = "z", x, y, sep = "", remove = FALSE, na.rm = TRUE)

### User defined function paste2()
paste2 <- function(x, sep = "") {paste(x[!is.na(x)], collapse = sep)}
dat %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(z = paste2(c(x, y)))
```

Add the following to the end of the pipe if the result should be `NA` when all elements are `NA`

```
mutate(z = if_else(z == "", NA, z))
```

Answer (score 0):

Updating @Erik Shilts solution in order to get rid of the last one comma:

```
x = gsub(",$", "", paste(1:4, ifelse(is.na(foo), "", foo), sep = ","))
```

Then in order to get rid of the trailing last `","`  in it just repeat it once again:

```
x <- gsub(",$", "", x)
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
library(stringr)

foo <- LETTERS[1:4]
foo[4] <- NA
foo
# [1] "A" "B" "C" NA 

if_else(!is.na(foo),
    str_c(1:4, str_replace_na(foo, ""), sep = ", "),
    str_c(1:4, str_replace_na(foo, ""), sep = "")
    )
# [1] "1, A" "2, B" "3, C" "4"
```