# Combine column to remove NA's

Tags: r, merge, na

I have some columns in R and for each row there will only ever be a value in one of them, the rest will be NA's. I want to combine these into one column with the non-NA value. Does anyone know of an easy way of doing this. For example I could have as follows:

```
data <- data.frame('a' = c('A','B','C','D','E'),
                   'x' = c(1,2,NA,NA,NA),
                   'y' = c(NA,NA,3,NA,NA),
                   'z' = c(NA,NA,NA,4,5))
```

So I would have

```
'a' 'x' 'y' 'z'  
 A   1   NA  NA  
 B   2   NA  NA  
 C  NA   3   NA  
 D  NA   NA  4  
 E  NA   NA  5
```

And I would to get

```
 'a' 'mycol'  
  A   1  
  B   2  
  C   3  
  D   4  
  E   5
```

The names of the columns containing NA changes depending on code earlier in the query so I won't be able to call the column names explicitly, but I have the column names of the columns which contains NA's stored as a vector e.g. in this example `cols <- c('x','y','z')`, so could call the columns using `data[, cols]`.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 78, accepted):

A `dplyr::coalesce` based solution could be as:

```
data %>% mutate(mycol = coalesce(x,y,z)) %>%
         select(a, mycol)
#   a mycol
# 1 A     1
# 2 B     2
# 3 C     3
# 4 D     4
# 5 E     5
```

**Data**

```
data <- data.frame('a' = c('A','B','C','D','E'),
                 'x' = c(1,2,NA,NA,NA),
                 'y' = c(NA,NA,3,NA,NA),
                 'z' = c(NA,NA,NA,4,5))
```

Answer (score 23):

You can use `unlist` to turn the columns into one vector. Afterwards, `na.omit` can be used to remove the `NA`s.

```
cbind(data[1], mycol = na.omit(unlist(data[-1])))

   a mycol
x1 A     1
x2 B     2
y3 C     3
z4 D     4
z5 E     5
```

Comment: This solution only works if the columns are ordered in function of the available data. The first column is not paired with the right value with other datasets like:

`data <- data.frame('a' = c('A','B','C','D','E'),'x' = c(NA,NA,3,NA,NA),'y' = c(1,2,NA,NA,NA),'z' = c(NA,NA,NA,4,5))`

Comment: This should deal with the issue raised by @julia: `cbind.data.frame(data[1], mycol=c(na.omit(c(t(data[, -1])))))`

Comment: I added a specific extension of this problem as a new post here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40878660/in-r-combine-column-to-remove-nas-yet-prioritize-specific-replacements.

Answer (score 17):

Here's a more general (but even simpler) solution which extends to all column types (factors, characters etc.) with non-ordered NA's. The strategy is simply to merge the non-NA values of other columns into your merged column using `is.na` for indexing:

```
data$mycol = data$x  # your new merged column. Start with x
data$mycol[!is.na(data$y)] = data$y[!is.na(data$y)]  # merge with y
data$mycol[!is.na(data$z)] = data$z[!is.na(data$z)]  # merge with z

> data
  a  x  y  z mycol
1 A  1 NA NA 1
2 B  2 NA NA 2
3 C NA  3 NA 3
4 D NA NA  4 4
5 E NA NA  5 5
```

Note that this will overwrite existing values in `mycol` if there are several non-NA values in the same row. If you have a lot of columns you could automate this by looping over `colnames(data)`.

Answer (score 15):

I would use `rowSums()` with the `na.rm = TRUE` argument:

```
cbind.data.frame(a=data$a, mycol = rowSums(data[, -1], na.rm = TRUE))
```

which gives:

```
> cbind.data.frame(a=data$a, mycol = rowSums(data[, -1], na.rm = TRUE))
  a mycol
1 A     1
2 B     2
3 C     3
4 D     4
5 E     5
```

You have to call the method directly (`cbind.data.frame`) as the first argument above is not a data frame.

Comment: Good solution. But what about character data?

Comment: As the OP's example didn't contain character data (other than the identifier column) I didn't consider that; other options here will handle that but at a cost; for example, unlisting a data frame with many rows and columns is going to be slow. If you have non-numeric data use another option, but if you don't this is a pretty trivial and relatively quick solution.

Answer (score 5):

Something like this ?

```
data.frame(a=data$a, mycol=apply(data[,-1],1,sum,na.rm=TRUE))
```

gives :

```
  a mycol
1 A     1
2 B     2
3 C     3
4 D     4
5 E     5
```

Comment: Yes, you're right, thanks for pointing this out ! I won't edit my post because it would make it a duplicate of Gavin Simpson's one.

Comment: Thanks juba, this works providing the columns are always numeric as they are in my example, but in reality the columns are sometimes character so I have used the above answer from Sven.

Answer (score 1):

max works too. Also works on strings vectors.

```
cbind(data[1], mycol=apply(data[-1], 1, max, na.rm=T))
```

Answer (score 1):

One possibility using `dplyr` and `tidyr` could be:

```
data %>%
 gather(variables, mycol, -1, na.rm = TRUE) %>%
 select(-variables)

   a mycol
1  A     1
2  B     2
8  C     3
14 D     4
15 E     5
```

Here it transforms the data from wide to long format, excluding the first column from this operation and removing the NAs.

Answer (score 0):

In a related link ([suppress NAs in paste()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13673894/suppress-nas-in-paste/31508774#31508774)) I present a version of `paste` with a `na.rm` option (with the unfortunate name of `paste5`).

With this the code becomes

```
cols <- c("x", "y", "z")
cbind.data.frame(a = data$a, mycol = paste2(data[, cols], na.rm = TRUE))
```

The output of `paste5` is a character, which works if you have character data otherwise you'll need to coerce to the type you want.

Answer (score 0):

Though this is not the OP case, it seems some people like the approach based on sums, how about thinking in mean and mode, to make the answer more universal. This answer matches the title, which is what many people will find.

```
data <- data.frame('a' = c('A','B','C','D','E'),
                   'x' = c(1,2,NA,NA,9),
                   'y' = c(NA,6,3,NA,5),
                   'z' = c(NA,NA,NA,4,5))

splitdf<-split(data[,c(2:4)], seq(nrow(data[,c(2:4)])))

data$mean<-unlist(lapply(splitdf, function(x)  mean(unlist(x), na.rm=T) ) )
data$mode<-unlist(lapply(splitdf, function(x)  {
  tab <- tabulate(match(x, na.omit(unique(unlist(x) )))); 
                  paste(na.omit(unique(unlist(x) ))[tab == max(tab) ], collapse = ", " )}) )

data
  a  x  y  z     mean mode
1 A  1 NA NA 1.000000    1
2 B  2  6 NA 4.000000 2, 6
3 C NA  3 NA 3.000000    3
4 D NA NA  4 4.000000    4
5 E  9  5  5 6.333333    5
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stick with base,

```
data <- data.frame('a' = c('A','B','C','D','E'),'x' = c(1,2,NA,NA,NA),'y' = c(NA,NA,3,NA,NA),'z' = c(NA,NA,NA,4,5))
data[is.na(data)]<-","
data$mycol<-paste0(data$x,data$y,data$z)
data$mycol <- gsub(',','',data$mycol)
```