# R: Combine columns ignoring NAs

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with a few columns, where for each row only one column can have a non-NA value. I want to combine the columns into one, keeping only the non-NA value, similar to this post:

[Combine column to remove NA's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14563531/combine-column-to-remove-nas)

However, in my case, some rows may contain only NAs, so in the combined column, we should keep an NA, like this (adapted from the post I mentioned):

```
data <- data.frame('a' = c('A','B','C','D','E','F'),
                   'x' = c(1,2,NA,NA,NA,NA),
                   'y' = c(NA,NA,3,NA,NA,NA),
                   'z' = c(NA,NA,NA,4,5,NA))
```

So I would have

```
  a  x  y  z
1 A  1 NA NA
2 B  2 NA NA
3 C NA  3 NA
4 D NA NA  4
5 E NA NA  5
6 F NA NA NA
```

And I would to get

```
 'a' 'mycol'  
  A   1  
  B   2  
  C   3  
  D   4  
  E   5  
  F   NA
```

The solution from the post mentioned above does not work in my case because of row F, it was:

```
cbind(data[1], mycol = na.omit(unlist(data[-1])))
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using base R...

```
data$mycol <- apply(data[,2:4], 1, function(x) x[!is.na(x)][1])

data
  a  x  y  z mycol
1 A  1 NA NA     1
2 B  2 NA NA     2
3 C NA  3 NA     3
4 D NA NA  4     4
5 E NA NA  5     5
6 F NA NA NA    NA
```

Answer (score 3):

One option is `coalesce` from `dplyr`

```
library(tidyverse)
data %>% 
   transmute(a, mycol = coalesce(!!! rlang::syms(names(.)[-1])))
#    a mycol
#1 A     1
#2 B     2
#3 C     3
#4 D     4
#5 E     5
#6 F    NA
```

---

Or we can use `max.col` from `base R`

```
cbind(data[1], mycol= data[-1][cbind(1:nrow(data), 
       max.col(!is.na(data[-1])) * NA^!rowSums(!is.na(data[-1]))+1)])
#   a mycol
#1 A     1
#2 B     2
#3 C     3
#4 D     4
#5 E     5
#6 F    NA
```

---

Or only with `rowSums`

```
v1 <- rowSums(data[-1], na.rm = TRUE)
cbind(data[1], mycol = v1 * NA^!v1)
```

---

Or another option is `pmax`

```
cbind(data[1], mycol = do.call(pmax, c(data[-1], na.rm = TRUE)))
```

or `pmin`

```
cbind(data[1], mycol = do.call(pmin, c(data[-1], na.rm = TRUE)))
```

Comment: could you specify which package you are using for the syms function? I see different packages with a function of the same name.