# R: Combining columns under precondition

Tags: r

I want to have a column's values equal another  column's values if the first column's value is NA in this row. So I want to change something like this

```
A  B
3  NA
NA NA
NA NA
5  NA
NA NA
NA NA
7  5
```

to something like this

```
A  B
3  3
NA NA
NA NA
5  5
NA NA
NA NA
7  5
```

I am fairly new to R and any other kind of programming.

Comment: suppose your data is in a `data.frame` called `dat`: `ifelse(is.na(dat$B), dat$A, dat$B)`

Comment: Have a look at `dplyr::coalesce()`. It will make problem simpler.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Combine column to remove NA's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14563531/combine-column-to-remove-nas)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per OP's description:

> equal another column's values if the first column's value is NA in
>   this row

Could you please try following and let me know if this helps you.

```
df21223$B[is.na(df21223$B[1])] <- df21223$A
```

Output will be as follows for data frame's B part:

```
> df21223$B
[1]  3 NA NA  5 NA NA  7
```

Where Sample data is:

```
> df21223$A
[1]  3 NA NA  5 NA NA  7
> df21223$B
[1] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
df$B[is.na(df$B)] <- df$A
```