# remove NA values and combine non NA values into a single column

Tags: r, na

I have a data set which has numeric and NA values in all columns. I would like to create a new column with all non NA values and preserve the row names

```
    v1  v2  v3  v4  v5
a   1   NA  NA  NA  NA 
b   NA  2   NA  NA  NA
c   NA  NA  3   NA  NA
d   NA  NA  NA  4   NA
e   NA  NA  NA  NA  5
```

I have tried using the coalesce function from dplyr

```
digital_metrics_FB <- fb_all_data %>%
                      mutate(fb_metrics = coalesce("v1", 
                                                   "v2", 
                                                   "v3", 
                                                   "v4",
                                                   "v5"))
```

and also tried an apply function

```
df2 <- sapply(fb_all_data,function(x) x[!is.na(x)])
```

still cannot get it to work.

I am looking for the final result to be where all non NA values come together in the final column and the row names are preserved

```
    final  
 a    1
 b    2
 c    3
 d    4
 e    5
```

any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Possible [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14563531/combine-column-to-remove-nas).

Comment: the solution to a similar question was not working for me so I had to ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `pmax`

```
do.call(pmax, c(fb_all_data , na.rm = TRUE))
```

If there are more than one non-NA element and want to combine as a string, a simple `base R` option would be

```
data.frame(final = apply(fb_all_data, 1, function(x) toString(x[!is.na(x)])))
```

---

Or using `coalesce`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)
fb_all_data  %>%
   rownames_to_column('rn') %>%
   transmute(rn, final = coalesce(v1, v2, v3, v4, v5)) %>%
   column_to_rownames('rn')
#   final
#a     1
#b     2
#c     3
#d     4
#e     5
```

Or using `tidyverse`, for multiple non-NA elements

```
fb_all_data %>%
      rownames_to_column('rn') %>%
      transmute(rn, final = pmap_chr(.[-1], ~ c(...) %>% 
                                 na.omit %>%
                                 toString)) %>%
      column_to_rownames('rn')
```

NOTE: Here we are showing data that the OP showed as example and not some other dataset

#### data

```
fb_all_data <- structure(list(v1 = c(1L, NA, NA, NA, NA), v2 = c(NA, 2L, NA, 
 NA, NA), v3 = c(NA, NA, 3L, NA, NA), v4 = c(NA, NA, NA, 4L, NA
  ), v5 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 5L)), class = "data.frame",
  row.names = c("a", 
 "b", "c", "d", "e"))
```

Comment: Couldn't we simplify your second approach to `data.frame(final = do.call(coalesce, fb_all_data), row.names = rownames(fb_all_data))`

Answer (score 1):

With `tidyverse`, you can do:

```
df %>%
 rownames_to_column() %>%
 gather(var, val, -1, na.rm = TRUE) %>%
 group_by(rowname) %>%
 summarise(val = paste(val, collapse = ", "))

  rowname val  
  <chr>   <chr>
1 a       1    
2 b       2, 3 
3 c       3    
4 d       4    
5 e       5
```

Sample data to have a row with more than one non-NA value:

```
df <- read.table(text = "    v1  v2  v3  v4  v5
a   1   NA  NA  NA  NA 
                 b   NA  2   3  NA  NA
                 c   NA  NA  3   NA  NA
                 d   NA  NA  NA  4   NA
                 e   NA  NA  NA  NA  5", header = TRUE)
```