# Merging the content of several columns into one

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe with five columns and 6 rows (actually they are many more, just trying to simplify matters):

```
One Two Three   Four    Five
Cat NA  NA  NA  NA
NA  Dog NA  NA  NA
NA  NA  NA  Mouse   NA
Cat NA  Rat NA  NA
Horse   NA  NA  NA  NA
NA NA NA NA NA
```

Now, I would like to coalesce all the information in a new single column ('Summary'), like this:

```
Summary
Cat
Dog
Mouse
Error
Horse
NA
```

Please note the 'Error' reported on the fourth Summary row, because two different values have been reported during the merging. I tried to look at the 'coalesce' function in the dplyr package, but it really desn't seem to do what I need.
Thanks in advance.

**Edited**: I added a 6th row to indicate that in case of all 'NA' in row, I would like to get 'NA' and not 'Errors' in my 'Summary' column. Sorry if this was not clear in my first post.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Combine column to remove NA's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14563531/combine-column-to-remove-nas)

Comment: What code have you tried exactly? You say "please note the error," but you didn't include what you did to return that as a value

Comment: @Adamm. Not really because doesn't handle the Error conditoin and also I have to name all the colnames

Answer (score 2):

Here is an idea via `apply`,

```
apply(df, 1, function(i){i1 <- i[!is.na(i)]; if(length(i1) > 1){'Error'}else{i1}})
#[1] "Cat"   "Dog"   "Mouse" "Error" "Horse"
```

Comment: hgh> library(RCurl)
> a <- getURL('https://download1645.mediafire.com/4zvabh0uqf6g/96px8ophovxrxe9/example.tab')
> df <- read.table(text=a,header=TRUE, sep = "\t")
> View(Normal1)

Answer (score 1):

I would use apply to solve this, since you need to handle specific cases. EG

```r
df <- structure(list(One = structure(c(1L, NA, NA, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("Cat", 
"Horse", "NA"), class = "factor"), Two = structure(c(NA, 1L, 
NA, NA, NA), .Label = c("Dog", "NA"), class = "factor"), Three = structure(c(NA, 
NA, NA, 2L, NA), .Label = c("NA", "Rat"), class = "factor"), 
    Four = structure(c(NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA), .Label = c("Mouse", 
    "NA"), class = "factor"), Five = structure(c(NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_), .Label = "NA", class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
-5L), class = "data.frame")


apply(df, 1, function(row) if(sum(!is.na(row)) == 1) na.omit(row)[[1]] else "Error")
#> [1] "Cat"   "Dog"   "Mouse" "Error" "Horse"
```

<sup>Created on 2020-01-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use the new `pivot_` function in `dplyr`:

```
df <- tribble(~One, ~Two, ~Three,   ~Four,    ~Five,
              "Cat", NA,  NA,  NA,  NA,
              NA,  "Dog", NA,  NA,  NA,
              NA,  NA,  NA,  "Mouse",   NA,
              "Cat", NA,  "Rat", NA,  NA,
              "Horse",   NA,  NA,  NA,  NA)

df %>% 
  pivot_longer(names_to = "variable", values_to = "Summary", 
               values_drop_na = TRUE, cols = One:Five) %>% 
  distinct(Summary)
# # A tibble: 5 x 1
# Summary
# <chr>  
# 1 Cat    
# 2 Dog    
# 3 Mouse  
# 4 Rat    
# 5 Horse
```

Comment: That doesn't handle the error condition the OP mentioned

Comment: @alanocallaghan wasn't clear in the OP, will have to edit.

Answer (score 0):

- Here is another base R solution, using `sapply()` + `ifelse()`

```
r <- sapply(as.list(as.data.frame(t(df))),
            function(x) ifelse(length(levels(x))==1, na.omit(as.vector(x)),"Error"))
```

such that

```
> r
     V1      V2      V3      V4      V5 
  "Cat"   "Dog" "Mouse" "Error" "Horse"
```

- Or you can use `sapply()` + `ifelse()`

```
r <- apply(df, 1, function(x) ifelse(length(z <- unique(na.omit(x)))==1, z,"Error"))
```

such that

```
> r
[1] "Cat"   "Dog"   "Mouse" "Error" "Horse"
```

**DATA**

```
df <- structure(list(One = c("Cat", NA, NA, "Cat", "Horse"), Two = c(NA, 
"Dog", NA, NA, NA), Three = c(NA, NA, NA, "Rat", NA), Four = c(NA, 
NA, "Mouse", NA, NA), Five = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

Comment: Thanks. Your example works great on the example I provided, but fails on my real test case (a 11x3170 dataframe, with col names):

library(RCurl)


a <- getURL('https://download1645.mediafire.com/4zvabh0uqf6g/96px8ophovxrxe9/example.tab')


df <- read.table(text=a,header=TRUE, sep = "\t")


r <- sapply(as.list(as.data.frame(t(df))),function(x) ifelse(length(levels(x))==1, na.omit(as.vector(x)),"Error"))


The second element of 'r' should be 'NA' not 'Error'. The same the third one, etc.

Comment: Sorry for the bad format of my previuos comment, but I wasn't able to edit the post. Hope you can go through it the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use coalesce

```
df %>%
  mutate_all(as.character) %>% 
  mutate(coal = coalesce(!!!syms(names(.))),
         sum_na = rowSums(!is.na(.)),
         result = if_else(sum_na == 1,coal,"Error")) %>% 
  select(result)
```

Comment: That doesn't handle the error condition the OP mentioned

Comment: @alanocallaghan Solved