# Pasting character vectors, removing NA's and separators between NAs

Tags: regex, string, r

I've got several character vectors that I want to paste together.  The problem is that some of the character vectors are pretty sparse.  So, when I paste them, I get NA's and extra separators.  How can I efficiently remove the NA's and extra separators while still joining the vectors?

I've got something like:

```
n1 = c("goats", "goats", "spatula", NA, "rectitude", "boink")
n2 = c("forever", NA, "...yes", NA, NA, NA)
cbind(paste(n1,n2, sep=", "))
```

which gives me:

```
[1,] "goats, forever" 
[2,] "goats, NA"      
[3,] "spatula, ...yes"
[4,] "NA, NA"         
[5,] "rectitude, NA"  
[6,] "boink, NA"
```

but I want:

```
[1,] "goats, forever" 
[2,] "goats"          
[3,] "spatula, ...yes"
[4,] <NA>
[5,] "rectitude"      
[6,] "boink"
```

There are clearly inefficient and tedious ways of doing this with a lot of regular expressions and string splitting.  But anything quick/simple?

Comment: Have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13673894/suppress-nas-in-paste

Answer (score 5):

Not a lot of regex, just 1 line and 1 more to replace `NA`

```
n1 <- c("goats", "goats", "spatula", NA, "rectitude", "boink")
n2 <- c("forever", NA, "...yes", NA, NA, NA)
n3 <- cbind(paste(n1,n2, sep=", "))
n3 <- gsub("(, )?NA", "", n3)
n3[n3==""] <- NA
```

Answer (score 5):

Code (no regex or string splitting):

```
vec <- apply(cbind(n1,n2),1,function(x)
    ifelse(all(is.na(x)), NA, paste(na.omit(x),collapse=", ")) )
```

Result:

```
> vec # as a vector
[1] "goats, forever"  "goats"  "spatula, ...yes"  NA  "rectitude"  "boink"

> cbind(vec) # as a matrix
     vec              
[1,] "goats, forever" 
[2,] "goats"          
[3,] "spatula, ...yes"
[4,] NA               
[5,] "rectitude"      
[6,] "boink"
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an option using the qdap package (though the other options seem better to me as they use base R):

```
library(qdap)
gsub(" ", ", ", blank2NA(Trim(gsub("NA", "", paste(n1, n2)))))

## [1] "goats, forever"  "goats"           "spatula, ...yes" NA               
## [5] "rectitude"       "boink"
```

Or...

```
## gsub(" ", ", ", blank2NA(gsub("NA| NA", "", paste(n1, n2))))
```