# paste two data.table columns

Tags: r, data.table

```
dt <- data.table(L=1:5,A=letters[7:11],B=letters[12:16])
   L A B
1: 1 g l
2: 2 h m
3: 3 i n
4: 4 j o
5: 5 k p
```

Now I want to paste columns "A" and "B" to get a new one, let's call it "new":

```
dt2
   L A B new
1: 1 g l  gl
2: 2 h m  hm
3: 3 i n  in
4: 4 j o  jo
5: 5 k p  kp
```

Comment: If you use a data frame you can just use paste: `dt <- data.frame(L=1:5,A=letters[7:11],B=letters[12:16])` 
`dt$new <- paste0(dt$A,dt$B)`

Comment: ok I just wanted to ask you to post it. I can't accept my own answer without waiting for 2 days...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[Arun's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18359456/paste-two-data-table-columns/18360123#comment26954825_18359456) answered this question:

```
dt[,new:=paste0(A,B)]
```

Comment: This is the precise method I used for a very similar task, however I decided to use the option `collapse = "."` as I am using the resulting column, `new`, as an ID of sorts, and the addition of the `collapse =` option changes the behaviour unexpectedly -- on a decently sized `data.table` it effectively froze R -- is this actually expected behaviour or a bug? ie: `dt[, new := paste0(A, B, collapse = "."]` which yields the following on the sample table used in this example: `l g l  l.h m.i n.j o.k p`

Comment: What to do if I want to name the column "new" as "AB" ie I want to append the column names as well

Comment: Just use names(dt)[names(dt)=="new"]<-"AB"

Answer (score 24):

I had a similar issue but had many columns, and didn't want to type them each manually.

### New version

(based on comment from @mnel)

```
dt[, new:=do.call(paste0,.SD), .SDcols=-1]
```

This is roughly twice as fast as the old version, and seems to sidestep the quirks.  Note the use of `.SDcols` to identify the columns to use in `paste0`.  The `-1` uses all columns but the first, since the OP wanted to paste columns A and B but not L.

If you would like to use a different separator:

```
dt[ , new := do.call(paste, c(.SD, sep = ":"))]
```

---

### Old version

You can use `.SD` and `by` to handle multiple columns:

```
dt[,new:=paste0(.SD,collapse=""),by=seq_along(L)]
```

I added `seq_along` in case L was not unique.  (You can check this using `dt<-data.table(L=c(1:4,4),A=letters[7:11],B=letters[12:16])`).

Also, in my actual instance for some reason I had to use `t(.SD)` in the `paste0` part.  There may be other similar quirks.

Comment: For this you should be using `do.call(paste0,.SD)`, eg `dt[ , new := do.call(paste0,.SD)]`

Comment: Good suggestion, and I'll add that you may need to use `.SDcols` too.  I've updated the answer.

Comment: I am curious if you know of a way to use the new version with a different separator?

Comment: how would I remove NAs in such a construct? `paste` doesn't accept `na.rm = TRUE`. `dt[ , new := do.call(paste, c(na.omit(.SD), sep = ':'))]` neither works.

Comment: found an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13673894/suppress-nas-in-paste

Comment: How is it specifying columns A & B? And what is `.SD` ?

Answer (score -1):

This should do it:

```
 dt <- data.table(dt, new = paste(dt$A, dt$B, sep = ""))
```

Comment: now I'm confused, this result was the first that came to my mind, too. Thought I checked this option. Anyway, thanks!

Comment: this is more data.table-like:  dt[,new:=paste(dt[,A],dt[,B],sep="")]

Comment: True. That works. I am more familiar with dataframes to be honest.

Answer (score -3):

If you want to paste strictly using column indexes (when you may not know the row names)...
I want to get a new column by pasting two columns 6 and 4

```
dt$new <- apply( dt[,c(6,4)], 1, function(row){ paste(row[1],row[2],sep="/") })
```

Comment: does this imply we cannot pass in column indices to paste?