# Paste two character columns with `data.table`

Tags: r, data.table

This question is a follow up to [paste two data.table columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18359456/paste-two-data-table-columns), and I'll therefore use the same example:

Start with a `data.table`:

```
dt <- data.table(L=1:5,A=letters[7:11],B=letters[12:16])
   L A B
1: 1 g l
2: 2 h m
3: 3 i n
4: 4 j o
5: 5 k p
```

I would like to create a new column that is the combination of two columns, `dt$A` and `dt$B` specifically.

```
dt[, new := paste0(A, B)]
dt
   L A B new
1: 1 g l  gl
2: 2 h m  hm
3: 3 i n  in
4: 4 j o  jo
5: 5 k p  kp
```

As I'm using `new` as a sort of ID column, and would prefer some human-readability, I want to use a character to separate the contents of `dt$A` and `dt$B`, so:

```
dt[, new := paste0(A, B, collapse = ".")]
```

But this alters the behaviour unexpectedly:

```
dt
   L A B            new
1: 1 g l gl.hm.in.jo.kp
2: 2 h m gl.hm.in.jo.kp
3: 3 i n gl.hm.in.jo.kp
4: 4 j o gl.hm.in.jo.kp
5: 5 k p gl.hm.in.jo.kp
```

Comment: Why are you using `collapse` instead of `sep`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `sep` as parameter to `paste()` instead of `collapse`:

```
dt[, new := paste(A, B, sep = ".")]
dt
#   L A B new
#1: 1 g l g.l
#2: 2 h m h.m
#3: 3 i n i.n
#4: 4 j o j.o
#5: 5 k p k.p
```

`paste0()` doesn't honor the `sep` parameter (see `?paste0`).

Comment: how can we use external variables having column names, inside the paste in the above example? e.g. ``cols_to_paste = c("A", "B") ``and then something like ``dt[, new := paste(cols_to_paste, sep = ".")]``

Comment: This is also what I'm trying to solve and what got me to this question. Any pointers?

Answer (score 0):

The above is the expected behaviour of `paste0` -- the solution to achieving the above is actually with `paste`:

Creating the column `new` as the concatenation of `dt$A` and `dt$B` with a character to separate the contents, use `paste` instead of `paste0`:

```
dt <- data.table(L=1:5,A=letters[7:11],B=letters[12:16])
dt[ , new := paste(A, B, collapse = ".")]
dt
   L A B new
1: 1 g l g.l
2: 2 h m h.m
3: 3 i n i.n
4: 4 j o j.o
5: 5 k p k.p
```

Using `paste0` with `collapse = "."` for example, changes the output of `paste0` as the documentation outlines:

*If a value is specified for* `collapse`, *the values in the result are then concatenated into a single string, with the elements being separated by the value of* `collapse`.

Comment: Just checked the help for `paste0`/`paste` and this appears to be in line with expectations: _If a value is specified for `collapse`, the values in the result are then concatenated into a single string, with the elements being separated by the value of `collapse`_.