# Directly paste two data table columns

Tags: r, data.table

I have a syntax question because I do not understand the behaveior of data.table for my problem.
Similiar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18359456/paste-two-data-table-columns) I want to paste two columns directly together using a predefined character vector. I do not want to create a new column.
MWE:

```
dt <- data.table(L=1:5,A=letters[7:11],B=letters[12:16])
cols<-c("A", "B")
```

I can paste directly using the col names without brackets as from the other question

```
dt[,paste0(A,B)]
```

But i cant using with=F or .SD

```
dt[,paste0(cols),with=F]
dt[,paste0(.SD),.SDcols=cols]
```

Why do I have to use a do.call?

```
dt[,do.call(paste0,.SD), .SDcols=cols]
```

Comment: What's wrong with `do.call`? It should be very efficient.

Comment: Reiterating David's point. It seems to accomplish what you need - what's wrong with `do.call`? If you're asking _why_ `do.call` works, recall that `.SD` (and your `data.table` `dt`) is just a "spruced-up"/regularized `list`. The syntax for `do.call` is `do.call(some_function, list_of_arguments)`.

Comment: Nothing wrong with it. But I do not understand the need to use it. I would have intuitively used with=F or .SDcols. I only by accident saw the do.call way in another slighly related post

Comment: imo, this is not a data.table issue but due to the implementation of `paste`

Comment: `do.call(f, args)` is R's (oddly named) idiom for passing a list of args, just like `f(*args)`/`f(**kwargs)` is the syntax in python.

Comment: Thanks for the effort, To be honest I still do not understand why I Need this to do what I want. I was hoping to understand this.