# Concatenate columns while removing duplicates & NA's

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to collapse string data from multiple columns into one summary column, however I wish to ignore NA's and duplicates. The data is varies, and duplicates and number of NAs vary across the data set and columns. I have pasted a reproducable data example below:

```
# example data 
data <- data.frame(id = c(1:4), A = c("one", "two", "threeA"),  B = c(NA, "two", "threeB"), C = c(NA, NA, NA))
data

  id      A      B  C
1  1   <NA>   <NA> NA
2  2    one   <NA> NA
3  3    two    two NA
4  4 threeA threeB NA

# desired result
  id              D
1  1           <NA>
2  2            one
3  3            two
4  4 threeA, threeB
```

I am really having trouble achieving both of these things (removing dupes and NA's) at the same time.

I'm using `dplyr` mostly, though am open to other suggestions. I've tried just using `paste` and `mutate`:

```
data %>%
  transmute(id, D = paste( A, B, C , sep = ", ") )
```

However that pastes `'NA'` text for `NA` values and pastes duplicates - and the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13673894/suppress-nas-in-paste) seems overly complicated and expensive (I have tens of thousands of rows).

I have tried using a combination of `group_by()` and `summarise()` in `dplyr` as well as `unique()` (having to unlist the data first)) and `paste()` as follows:

```
data %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  summarize(D = paste( unique( unlist(  A, B, C )) , sep = ", ") 
  )
```

This also pastes NAs, but I can easily remove this later, however it only pastes the FIRST unique value found, not all unique values.

Any suggestions on how to achieve this?

Comment: na.omit does not work in this case (I do not want to apply this to ALL columns in the df, just a select subset) - plus I also need to remove duplicates at the same time.

Comment: Could try `data %>% gather(variable, value, -id) %>% group_by(id) %>% summarise(toString(unique(value[!is.na(value)])))` or such

Comment: Hi @DavidArenburg. what is gather and what does it do? it's not a dplyr or base function.

Comment: It's from `tidyr`- yet another Hadleyverse package. It converts a wide data to a long format

Comment: @renegademonkey works for me with your given data `apply(data[-1], 1, function(x) toString(unique(na.omit(x))))`

Comment: @RonakShah that's it. I had tried something similar before but must have gotten the wrong syntax. I like that it doesn't require additional packages.