# How to compare a data frame to a list, and return values in the data frame matching the list?

Tags: r, grepl

Total newbie R question.  I have a data frame df of ID and Notes:

```
ID    Notes
1     dogs are friendly
2     dogs and cats are pets
3     cows live on farms
4     cats and cows start with c
```

I have another list of values "animals"

```
cats
cows
```

I want to add another column "match" to my data frame that contains all of the animals in the Notes, e.g

```
ID    Notes                        Matches
1     dogs are friendly            
2     dogs and cats are pets       cats
3     cows live on farms           cows
4     cats and cows start with c   cats, cows
```

So far the only luck I've had is using grepl to return if there are any matches:

```
grepl(paste(animals,collapse="|"),df$Notes,ignore.case = T)
```

How do I return the values instead?

**Update**
There are some rows in my data frame where I have multiple instance of cats, for example, in my Notes:

```
ID    Notes                             Matches
1     dogs are friendly            
2     dogs and cats are pets            cats
3     cows live on farms                cows
4     cats and cats cows start with c   cats, cows
```

I only want to return one instance of the match.  @LachlanO gets me very close with his solution, but I get:

```
[1] "NA, NA"                      "cats, NA"                    "NA, cows"                    "c(\"cats\", \"cats\"), cows"
```

How can I return only distinct matches?

Comment: Try `stringr::str_extract_all` insted of `grepl`.

Comment: Or something like: `df$Matches <- sapply(strsplit(tolower(df$Notes), " "), function(x) toString(intersect(x, animals)))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:** Added a `unique` operation to deal with duplicate matches.

I can start you off, then point you in a direction :)

The below uses stringr::str_extract_all to extract the relevant bits we need, but it unfortunately leaves us with bits we don't, most notably when it's blank. The `unique` function in the middle of our custom function just makes sure we take the unique matches element by element.

```
ID = seq(1,4)
Notes <- c(
  "dogs are friendly",
  "dogs and cats are pets",
  "cows live on farms",
  "cats and cows start with c "
)
df <- data.frame(ID, Notes)

animals = c("cats", "cows")

matches <- as.data.frame(sapply(animals, function(x){sapply(stringr::str_extract_all(df$Notes, x), unique)}, simplify = TRUE))
matches[matches == "character(0)"] <- NA

apply(matches, 1, paste, collapse = ", ")
[1] "NA, NA"     "cats, NA"   "NA, cows"   "cats, cows"
```

You could set this as your extra column, except it's no good because of those NAs. If there was a paste function which ignored NAs we'd be set.

Luckily another user has already solved this problem :) [Check out this answer here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13673894/suppress-nas-in-paste)

That in combination with the above should give you a suitable solution!

Comment: This is getting me very close--except in my dataset I have can have multiple mentions of a word, and only want to see a single match.  See my edit for an example.  Thank you!

Comment: @epr8n just stick in a `unique()` before the `paste()`.

Comment: @Gregor Getting a "unique() applies only to vectors" when trying: apply(matches, 1, unique(paste), collapse = ", ")

Comment: `apply(matches, 1, function(x) paste(unique(x), collapse = ",")`

Comment: @Gregor unfortunately that still leaves me [1] "NA"                         "cats,NA"                    "NA,cows"                    "c(\"cats\", \"cats\"),cows"

Comment: @epr8n, I've modified my answer and put the `unique` function in the right spot as @Gregor suggested. Now it returns the matches only once. Does this work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would do it:

```
animals = c("cats", "cows")
reg = paste(animals, collapse = "|")

library(stringr)
matches = str_extract_all(Notes, reg)
matches = lapply(matches, unique)
matches = sapply(matches, paste, collapse = ",")

df$matches = matches
df
#   ID                       Notes   matches
# 1  1           dogs are friendly          
# 2  2      dogs and cats are pets      cats
# 3  3          cows live on farms      cows
# 4  4 cats and cows start with c  cats,cows
```

If you want to fancy it up, paste word boundaries on the regex, like `reg = paste("\\b", animals, "\\b", collapse = "|")` to avoid extracting the middle of words.

---

Using the data nicely provided by LachlanO:

```
ID = seq(1,4)
Notes <- c(
  "dogs are friendly",
  "dogs and cats are pets",
  "cows live on farms",
  "cats and cows start with c "
)
df <- data.frame(ID, Notes)
```

Comment: Thank you @Gregor, exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `gsub` to be able to obtain all the animals at once:

```
gsub(".*?(cows|cats )|.*","\\1",do.call(paste,df),perl = T)
[1] ""          "cats "     "cows"      "cats cows"
```

Thus to write in one lane:

```
transform(df,matches=gsub(".*?(cows|cats )|.*","\\1",do.call(paste,df),perl = T))
  ID                       Notes   matches
1  1           dogs are friendly          
2  2      dogs and cats are pets     cats 
3  3          cows live on farms      cows
4  4 cats and cows start with c  cats cows
```