# Create a new variable by pasting two factor variables

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

If the two columns in my dataframe are:

```
species <- c("Dengue", "Dengue", "Dengue", "Dengue", "Dengue", "Dengue", "Dengue", "Dengue")
```

And

```
strain <- c(1, NA, 2, NA, NA, 3, 4, 5)
```

How do I get a column that combines the two to say Dengue 1, etc.?

Comment: `paste(species, strain)`?

Comment: @d.b thanks! this works and is easy. but the NAs are getting pasted. How do I not have them? I don't want Dengue NA

Comment: Possible duplicate of [suppress NAs in paste()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13673894/suppress-nas-in-paste)

Comment: What's your desired output? What do you want in the case of "Dengue" and NA?

Answer (score 1):

We can use `unite`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
df1 %>% 
     unite(species, species, strain)
```

---

If the `NA` needs to remain as `NA`, use `str_c`

```
df1 %>%
   transmute(species = str_c(species, strain, sep="_")) %>%
   fill(species)
```

If it is to `filter` out the `NAs`, then do the `filter` first

```
df1 %>%
   filter(!is.na(strain)) %>%
   transmute(species = str_c(species, strain, sep="_"))
```

#### data

```
df1 <- data.frame(species, strain)
```

Comment: Thanks @akrun. I tried and got the following error message.......no applicable method for 'unite_' applied to an object of class "character"
Also, what is the name of the dataset in the code and the name of the new variable?

Comment: @Martin I created the dataset using your vectors only

Comment: @Martin For the `NA` cases, what do you want to return

Comment: yes indeed. I tried it on my dataset and got the error message. I see your point. I don't want the NA on the new variable. I would also like the new variable to be called agent and the name of the dataframe can remain as df1. Thanks

Comment: @Martin  Sorry, I can't reproduce the error with `packageVersion('tidyr')#
[1] ‘1.0.0’`

Comment: Thanks @akrun . I have edited the code to suit the one you gave and now got the following error message Error: Evaluation error: could not find function "str_c".
My package version is '0.8.2'. I suppose I need to update the version or is it not safe?

Comment: @Martin  sorry, I forgot to add that.  It is `library(stringr)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ifelse` to suppress `NA` in your final output:

```r
paste0(species, ifelse(is.na(strain),"",strain))

 #>  [1] "Dengue1" "Dengue"  "Dengue2" "Dengue"  "Dengue"  "Dengue3" "Dengue4" "Dengue5"
```