# R Paste - ignore cases where at least one element I am pasting is NA

Tags: r, paste

I have the following vector:

```
vector1 <- c("A", "B", "C" , NA, NA, "D")
```

I want to apply this function paste ignoring NA values in vector1

```
vector2 <- paste("#", vector1, "something", sep = "")
```

and obtain this

```
vector2 <- c("#Asomething", "#Bsomething" , "#Csomething", NA, NA, "#Dsomething")
```

I want to avoid ex-post solutions using sub where I just get rid of elements containing the letters "NA" in the string.

I saw a similar question: [suppress NAs in paste()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13673894/suppress-nas-in-paste) however there they want to ignore NA and simply paste #something whereas I want NA to be displayed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine it with ifelse like this

```
ifelse(is.na(vector1), NA, paste("#", vector1, "something" ,sep = ""))
```

Although this was marked as answered please also see the answer of @hello_friend which may be more appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

Base R solution:

```
vector2 <- ifelse(is.na(vector1), NA_character_, paste("#", vector1, "something" ,sep = ""))
```

Comment: Did not see your answer which is pretty much the same. Why do you use `NA_character_` and not just `NA`?

Comment: @machine NA is of type logical, NA_character is of type character. vector_1 is a character vector, vector_2 is also explicitly a character vector.

Comment: But isn't it another vector than the OP asked for? `c("#Asomething", "#Bsomething" , "#Csomething" ,NA , NA, "#Dsomething")`

Comment: @machine No. Its a matter of typing. As in, the data.type of the vector, explicitly typing prevents any problems of unintended type conversion; in this instance an unintended consquence may be conversion to a factor vetor, when OP wants a character vector.

Comment: I see. +1 from me! Did not know that it is possible to define NA in a certain class.

Comment: @machine no worries, cheers ! Yes NA alone is of type logical ! Also interesting discussion on the negatives of the tidyverse post, post should not have been marked as duplicate!

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use `sapply()` with a anonymous function.

Please, have a look at the following code which does what you want.

```r
vector1 <- c("A", "B" , "C" ,NA_character_ , NA_character_, "D")
vector2 <- sapply( vector1, function( x ) 
  ifelse( is.na( x ), 
          NA_character_, 
          paste("#", x, "something" ,sep = "") ),
  USE.NAMES = FALSE
)
vector2
#> [1] "#Asomething" "#Bsomething" "#Csomething" NA            NA           
#> [6] "#Dsomething"
```

<sup>Created on 2020-05-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>