# Converting the format of a dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I am new in this forum, sorry for any issues... I have a dataframe (classification of substances with the classes) in the following format:

|  | A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Organic compounds | Benzenoids | Benzene | NA |
| 2 | Organic compounds | Benzenoids | Benzene | NA |
| 3 | Organic compounds | Organic oxygen compounds | NA | NA |
| 4 | NA | NA | NA | NA |
| 5 | Organic compounds | Benzenoids | NA | NA |

At the end i need a dataframe with 2 columns. The result should be something like this:

| class | count |
| --- | --- |
| Organic compounds; Benzenoids; Benzene | 2 |
| Organic compounds; Organic oxygen compounds | 1 |
| Organic compounds; Benzenoids | 1 |

What is my first step?
I tried to create a new column with the paste content of all the other columns like this:

`df$class <- paste(df$A,df$B,df$C,df$D ,sep = "; ")`

But the result is:

| class |
| --- |
| Organic compounds; Benzenoids; Benzene; NA |
| Organic compounds; Benzenoids; Benzene; NA |
| Organic compounds; Organic oxygen compounds; NA; NA |
| NA; NA; NA; NA |
| Organic compounds; Benzenoids; NA; NA |

What would be a conceivable approach for this problem, to get the final result?

Thanks alot!

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13673894/15573469)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    library(dplyr)

    df$class<-gsub('; NA','',  paste(df$A,df$B,df$C,df$D ,sep = "; ") )
    df <- df[df$class!='NA',]
    
    df<-ddply(df,.(class),summarize, count=length(class) )
```

Answer (score 0):

Will this work:

```
library(dplyr)
library(string)
df %>% mutate(across(everything(),~ replace_na(., ''))) %>% 
   mutate(class = trimws(paste(A,B,C,D, sep = ';'),whitespace = "''"), class = str_remove(class, ';+$')) %>% 
   count(class, name = 'count') %>% filter(!str_detect(class,'^$'))
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  class                                      count
  <chr>                                      <int>
1 Organic compounds;Benzenoids                   1
2 Organic compounds;Benzenoids;Benzene           2
3 Organic compounds;Organic oxygen compounds     1
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! The solution from @Ashish Baid  is a bit better for me to understand.