# C++ String Concatenation operator<<

Tags: c++, string, string-concatenation

I have realised my mistake. I was trying to concatenate two strings.

I have just started to learn C++. I have a problem about string concatenation.
I don't have problem when I use:

```
cout << "Your name is"<<name;
```

But when I try to do it with a string:

```
string nametext;
nametext = "Your name is" << name;
cout << nametext;
```

I got an error. How can I concatenate two strings?

Comment: Is `name` an `std::string`?

Comment: `<<` is the "put to" operator for `cout`. It is not used for `std::string` or C style strings (`char *`).

Comment: For the future, it's possible to do this with things that just + doesn't work on with `std::ostringstream`.

Comment: check out this

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4304662/c-concatenating-strings

Answer (score 35):

For string concatenation in C++, you should use the `+` operator.

```
nametext = "Your name is" + name;
```

Comment: Doesn't work, I am getting "Invalid operands to binary expression ('const char *' and 'const char *')"

The error lies in this line:
    std::string helloWorld = "Hello," + " World!";

What am I doing wrong? both "Hello," and " World!" are valid strings (I can declare, assign, and print them seperately), but it's raising some weird error abour char* ?

Comment: @GregoryFenn C++ is trying to be backwards compatible with C therefore a raw literal string, which is `"string"` will be a const char* and not a C++ string. In c++ you cant overload operators that take primitive types on both sides, which means you have to convert one of them to string. This will work: `std::string helloWorld = "Hello" + std::string(" World!");`

Comment: Awesome! That makes it a lot clearer :) I'm used to C# so some of these technical points seem quite odd to me, it seems strange to me to try to be backwards compatible, but that's just me.

Comment: @GregoryFenn Yea the raw literal strings in C++ are very confusing if you dont know about them beforehand

Answer (score 13):

First of all it is unclear what type name has. If it has the type `std::string` then instead of

```
string nametext;
nametext = "Your name is" << name;
```

you should write

```
std::string nametext = "Your name is " + name;
```

where operator + serves to concatenate strings.

If `name` is a character array then you may not use operator + for two character arrays (the string literal is also a character array), because character arrays in expressions are implicitly converted to pointers by the compiler. In this case you could write

```
std::string nametext( "Your name is " );
nametext.append( name );
```

or

```
std::string nametext( "Your name is " );
nametext += name;
```

Answer (score 4):

`nametext` is an `std::string` but these do not have the stream insertion operator (`<<`) like output streams do.

To concatenate strings you can use the [`append`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/append/) member function (or its equivalent, `+=`, which works in the exact same way) or the [`+` operator](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/operator+/), which creates a new string as a result of concatenating the previous two.

Answer (score 4):

You can combine strings using stream string like that:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string name = "Bill";
    stringstream ss;
    ss << "Your name is: " << name;
    string info = ss.str();
    cout << info << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`nametext = "Your name is" + name;`

I think this should do