# How do I concatenate "constant strings" and chars?

Tags: c++, string, char

What is the "proper way" to do the following? (Note, I don't want to output the message to the screen (yet), the data needs to be stored in a variable.)

```
std::cout << "Enter a letter: ";    
char input;
std::cin >> input;

std::string message = "Today's program was brought to you by the letter '" + input + "'.";
```

The code gives me the error message *invalid operands of types `const char*` and `const char [3]` to binary `operator+`*.

I understand why this message is occurring. When Googling for a solution, the results that come up recommend casting each item into a string in turn. However, this becomes impractical if you have to concatenate a dozen items:

```
std::string("x:") + x + std::string(", y:") + y + std::string(", width:") + width + std::string(", height:") + height + ...;
```

What is the "proper way" in c++ to concatenate strings, chars, char arrays, and any other data that is convertible, into a single string? Is there anything like [Python's beautiful string formatting features](http://www.diveintopython.net/native_data_types/formatting_strings.html) in c++?

Comment: Yes, Boost.Format is somewhat like Python and there are plenty of small, modern, typesafe formatting libraries.

Answer (score 4):

What you are trying to do won't work because C++ views your concatenation as an attempt to add several `char` pointers.  If you explicitly cast the *first* element in the series to an `std::string` it should work.

Change your original code

```
string message = "Today's program was brought to you by the letter '" + input + "'.";
```

to this:

```
string message = std::string("Today's program was brought to you by the letter '")
    + input + "'.";
```

q.v. [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4304662/c-concatenating-strings) which discusses this problem in greater detail (though I don't know why it got closed as not being a real question).

Comment: But as I mentioned in the question, if I'm adding together a collection of a dozen items (e.g. `"a:" + a + ", b:" + b + ", c:" + c + ...`) isn't that going to result in a lot of `std::string` casts?

Comment: You only need to construct a `std::string` from the first element. `std::string` + string literal is a defined operation

Comment: @DavidStone Ah, yes, I see! The `+` operation on the first element returns another `std::string` which has that operation defined on it, etc.

Comment: In fact, in that case the code can be _even_ simpler by starting the line with a "dummy" empty string: `std::string() + "Today's program..." + input`

Comment: @IQAndreas Very nice answer.

Answer (score 2):

There's several ways to do this, but one way that's a good balance between simplicity of implementation and convenience is to use a "formatter" class which wraps `std::stringstream` like so:

```
string message = formatter() << "Today's program was brought to you by the letter '" << input << "'.";
```

Where formatter can be defined very simply in a header file as follows:

```
#include <sstream>

class formatter {
public:
    template <typename T>
    formatter & operator<<(const T & o) {
        stream_ << o;
        return *this;
    }

    const std::string str() const { return stream_.str(); }

    operator std::string() {
            return stream_.str();
    }

private:
    std::ostringstream stream_;
};
```

What's going on there: If you try to use a temporary `std::stringstream()` instead of `formatter()` above, it doesn't work because

- `std::stringstream` is not implicitly convertible to `std::string`
- You can't even do it like this
  `std::string message = (std::stringstream() << "foo" << input << "bar").str();` because, `std::stringstream` returns `std::ostream &` from its stream operations (rather than `std::stringstream &`), and you cannot convert an `ostream` to a `string` in general.

The formatter class just lets you construct and use a `stringstream` all in one line with a minimum of boiler plate.

Comment: An important benefit here is that this approach lets you stream numbers and other types that you can't directly concatenate to a `string`.  `operator std::string()` can be made `const`.  For whatever it's worth - `static_cast<std::ostringstream&>(std::ostringstream() << x << y << z).str()` "works" but is too clumsy and verbose to be desirable for widespread use....